# Clojure unable to resolve symbol in repl

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I'm doing the Exercise 4.12 in Packt Publishing's The Clojure Workshop (source code on [Github](https://github.com/PacktWorkshops/The-Clojure-Workshop/tree/master/Chapter04/Exercise4.12)).

The instructions were to create a [deps.edn](https://github.com/PacktWorkshops/The-Clojure-Workshop/blob/master/Chapter04/Exercise4.12/deps.edn) file and a [tennis.clj](https://github.com/PacktWorkshops/The-Clojure-Workshop/blob/master/Chapter04/Exercise4.12/src/packt_clj/tennis.clj) file and in an REPL (I'm using clj) type the following:

```
(in-ns 'packt-clj.tennis)

(first-match "match_scores_1991-2016_unindexed_csv.csv")
```

When I try to call firs-match, whether in `./` `./src/` or `./src/pakt_clj/` I get the error

> Unable to resolve symbol: first-match in this context

Any help in getting this to work is much appreciated.

Comment: Don't forget to `load` the file containing the `first-match` function definition. https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/load `(load "packt-clj/tennis")`